# What is Bsum in (meta-)regression and how do you test for its significance?

Tags: multiple-regression, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I received a reviewer report on a meta-analysis that I submitted which stated that a multivariate regression that I performed should instead be "a backward stepwise multivariate logistic regression analysis since Bsum is insignificant".

Ignoring the fact that every source I know says that stepwise procedures should be avoided, what is Bsum and how do you test for it? I suppose it is the sum of coefficients, but I don't seem to find anything about it. And how did the reviewer find out it was not significant since they don't have access to the dataset itself to compute the model themselves?

Comment: Presumably in the multivariable model you fitted none of the variables reached some arbitrary level of statistical significance and that is what the reviewer picked up on and which drives their mis-guided attempt to force you to do a stepwise model. Incidentally I am assuming you mean multivariable not multivariate. You could always politely ask the editor to get the reviewer to explain the term. |How you deal with their obsession with variable selection is another issue.